# SVN Export Command Runs Successfully but Files do not appear at target path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, svn

I am running into the issue of specifying a server:target_path when running the svn export command and files not actually appearing where I think they should be.

example:
Running export_script.bash on Server 1 exporting files to Server 2

pseudo-code:

svn export --username $u --password $pw --non-interactive --force $svnurl $server:$target_path

The terminal shows the output as being successful but when I navigate to the server 2 file path no files are present.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like no proper read/write permission in the directory where you are trying to check out files. Add proper file permission first and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I gave my directory at the target path 777 permissions and reran the script. I was met with the same results - terminal showed the output but the files did not appear.

Comment: You have given file read write permission in the directory. But it also need access permission to that directory location as well. For example /app/codes/svn/location here svn should have permission to access `location` directory as well.